# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error L

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using Pyodbc to connect SQL Server in windows:

I can connect and login the SQL Server database by using SSMS 18.

But not able to connect it through Python:

```
server = 'DESKTOP-E111111\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'my_database'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; \
                       SERVER=' + server + '; \
                       DATABASE=' + database + ';\
                       Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I have tried user name and password to connect but failed to.

I have checked the database status, it is running.

I have enabled TCP/IP.

The error:

> File "e:/Users/willi/PycharmProjects/rf/new_robot_2022/insert_to_db.py", line 26, in 
> cnxn =pyodbc.connect('''DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};
> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]MAX_PROVS: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].  (-1) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
> instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (-1)')

Anyone can help?

Comment: The SQL Browser service, responsible for instance name resolution, only enumerates the SQL Server protocol configurations when it first starts. Did you stop and restart the SQL Browser service after enabling and configuring the TCP/IP protocol for your instance?

Comment: yes,I restarted the SQL Browser service after enabling and configuring the TCP/IP protocol for my instance